# how to create iCal feed .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, icalendar

I have created a method that outputs an iCal file when a user clicks a button. However, I would like to have the users to subscribe to my feed.

Currently, the events are stored in the database and the method gets them in the proper format before sending the file to user.

From my understanding, in order for the feed to work, I need to have a file to be physically located on the server as opposed to be dynamically generated.

Is there anything I can do so that the url for the feed woudl be actually my page that would return the requested file in iCal format?

In other words, since I'm using C#, all my pages are [name].ASPX, I imagine that instead of ASPX, the feed needs to have a different extension.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here's a link to get you started: https://arunjameskc.wordpress.com/2012/10/10/implementing-custom-sharepoint-icalendar-ics-requests-using-httphandler/